# Problems with Rails Server: WEBrick appears to boot, but localhost:3000 and variations do not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I navigate to my app and do the following:

```
rails server -b localhost
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
```

However, when I navigate to http://localhost:3000 in any browser, I get a cannot display error. Same issue when using 127.0.0.1:3000 or 0.0.0.1:3000

If I go simply to http://localhost then I see a directory listing of my app.

Any ideas and suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: try it without that -b flag, does it still happen?

Comment: What OS, and what ruby/rails versions do you have installed?

Comment: Yes, it happens even without the -b flag. Rails 3.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: have you run "bundle install" to make sure you have everything you need? -- also, when you say "cannot display error" what do you mean? are you seeing an error page from rails or the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can bind to a hostname, only an ip. try -b 127.0.0.1 and the navigate to localhost:3000 which should point to 127.0.0.1